# Eclipse Scout Neon importFormFieldData in template

Tags: eclipse-scout

I have template group box, for reuse purposes.

In this template I have function witch need to fill data inside this template.
Because you can't create new instance of `FormData` in template I have abstract function for getting new instance of form data. Then each form that use this template implement this method.

```
 protected abstract AbstractMyBoxData getFormData();
```

My function is look like this :

```
 public void setValuesInTemplates(Long parameter)
 {
    AbstractMyBoxData formData = this.getFormData();
    this.exportFormFieldData(formData);
    formData = BEANS.get(iMyService.class).setSomeValue(parameter);
    this.importFormFieldData(formData, true);
 }
```

My problem is that I get correct form data from service, but when I import this form data, template does not change UI.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the implementation of `importFormFieldData(..)` for groupboxes.
The implementation is defined here:

```
AbstractFormField.importFormFieldData(AbstractFormFieldData, boolean)
```

… and it is empty.

The complete explanation (and a solution) can be found here:

[Table and GroupBox for details on row selection](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/583077/1172004/#msg_1172004)

[You probably need to redo it for Neon, but the changes are not so big. Most of the code in `FormDataUtility2` is copy pasted from `AbstractForm`].

I am convinced that it is a mistake to have the import logic hardcoded in the Form, but I did not manage to convince the team back then. Feel free to add a comment in forum Post.

Comment: I have mentioned this topic on the [Scout Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1720815/#msg_1720815). Please read the important advice I have added if you need to import both the complete `FormData` and your `GroupBoxData`